# Why the mean is not centered at 0 and 1 respectively for both the graphs?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
a1 = np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=2,size=1000) 
h1, b1 = np.histogram(a1,bins=10,density=True) 
plt.plot(h1, color='r') 
a2 = np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=5,size=30) 
h2, b2 = np.histogram(a1,bins=5,density=True) 
plt.plot(h2, color='g') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Consider that in order to plot something on a 2D plane you need *two* coordinates, `plot(x,y)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest didn't get the reason.

Comment: You made two histograms of the *same* random sample (you each time used `a1` instead of `a1` and `a2`).

Comment: But the reason is: you just plotted the bins, you did not take into account the span of these bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not take into account the *span* of the bins. Indeed, you even made bins for the *same* random sample `a1`, and not of the two different samples `a1` and `a2`. We can for example calculate the middle of the bins with:

```
>>> 0.5*(b1[:-1]+b1[1:])
array([-6.01624486, -4.69961062, -3.38297639, -2.06634215, -0.74970792,
        0.56692632,  1.88356055,  3.20019479,  4.51682903,  5.83346326])
```

If we then make plots of the two distributions, we see:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1 = np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=2,size=1000) 
h1, b1 = np.histogram(a1,bins=10,density=True)
b1m = 0.5*(b1[:-1]+b1[1:])

plt.plot(b1m, h1, color='r') 
a2 = np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=5,size=30) 
h2, b2 = np.histogram(a2,bins=5,density=True)
b2m = 0.5*(b2[:-1]+b2[1:])

plt.plot(b2m, h2, color='g') 
plt.show()
```

we then see:

[image: two normals]